# Multiple SQL JOIN with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, select, join

```
SELECT A.SspStudent, 
       B.StuLastName, 
       B.StuFirstName,
       C.TerDescription, 
       A.SspCourseSubject, 
       A.SspCourseID,
       A.SspCreditHours, 
       A.SspStatus,
       B.StuEmailUNCW, 
       B.StuAdvisorEmail,
       B.StuApplicationStatus,
       D.UseName 
FROM ((tblStudentSchedulePerm A
      INNER JOIN tblStudent B 
           ON (A.SspStudent = B.StuID AND
               B.StuAdmitTerm <> '201520A' AND
               A.SspStatus = 'Schedul' AND 
              (A.SspTerm = '201520A' OR A.SspTerm = '201520B') AND
               A.SspCreditHours <> 0))
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTerms C 
           ON A.SspTerm = C.TerTermPart)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN D tblUser
           ON B.StuAdvisorEmail = D.UseEmail;
```

I am trying to make this query work but everytime I try to adjust the parenthesis I get an error.
Could I get some help??

Comment: what are you trying to do, what have you tried. and what is the error?  what db are you using? and what does the data look like?

Comment: I don't understand why you have so many parens here.  Most are unneeded.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus . . . It looks like someone learned to write SQL through MS Access first.  No comment.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I would limit the `JOIN` conditions to those who are actually related to the relation. The other conditions (like `A.SspStatus = 'Schedul'`) should go to a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

you are better off, with out those parenthesis, also you need to a sub query in the joins

Retained the parenthesis except in the OR AND condition , try this out.

```
SELECT A.SspStudent, 
       B.StuLastName, 
       B.StuFirstName, 
       C.TerDescription, 
       A.SspCourseSubject, 
       A.SspCourseID, 
       A.SspCreditHours, 
       A.SspStatus, 
       B.StuEmailUNCW, 
       B.StuAdvisorEmail, 
       B.StuApplicationStatus, 
       D.UseName 
FROM   tblStudentSchedulePerm A 
       INNER JOIN tblStudent B 
       ON A.SspStudent = B.StuID 
          AND B.StuAdmitTerm <> '201520A' 
          AND A.SspStatus = 'Schedul' 
          AND ( A.SspTerm = '201520A' 
                OR A.SspTerm = '201520B' ) 
          AND A.SspCreditHours <> 0 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTerms C 
                     ON A.SspTerm = C.TerTermPart 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN  tblUser  D
                    ON B.StuAdvisorEmail = D.UseEmail;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
D tblUser
```

should be :

```
tblUser D
```

Other than that, remove all useless parentheses:

```
SELECT A.SspStudent, 
       B.StuLastName, 
       B.StuFirstName, 
       C.TerDescription, 
       A.SspCourseSubject, 
       A.SspCourseID, 
       A.SspCreditHours, 
       A.SspStatus, 
       B.StuEmailUNCW, 
       B.StuAdvisorEmail, 
       B.StuApplicationStatus, 
       D.UseName 
FROM   tblStudentSchedulePerm A 
         INNER JOIN tblStudent B 
                 ON  A.SspStudent = B.StuID 
                      AND B.StuAdmitTerm <> '201520A' 
                      AND A.SspStatus = 'Schedul' 
                      AND ( A.SspTerm = '201520A' 
                             OR A.SspTerm = '201520B' ) 
                      AND A.SspCreditHours <> 0 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTerms C 
                      ON A.SspTerm = C.TerTermPart
         LEFT OUTER JOIN tblUser D
                      ON B.StuAdvisorEmail = D.UseEmail;
```

Comment: all the parens except the ones on the B inner join :-p

Answer (score 1):

I indented your query. This is how I usually start to pick apart something with which I'm unfamilar.

```
SELECT
    A.SspStudent
    , B.StuLastName
    , B.StuFirstName
    , C.TerDescription
    , A.SspCourseSubject
    , A.SspCourseID
    , A.SspCreditHours
    , A.SspStatus
    , B.StuEmailUNCW
    , B.StuAdvisorEmail
    , B.StuApplicationStatus
    , D.UseName
FROM
    (
        (
        tblStudentSchedulePerm A
            INNER JOIN tblStudent B ON
                (
                A.SspStudent = B.StuID
                AND B.StuAdmitTerm <> '201520A'
                AND A.SspStatus = 'Schedul'
                AND (A.SspTerm = '201520A' OR A.SspTerm = '201520B')
                AND A.SspCreditHours <> 0
                )
        )
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTerms C ON A.SspTerm = C.TerTermPart
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN D tblUser ON B.StuAdvisorEmail = D.UseEmail
;
```

Comment: Did you change anything at all ? Indenting usually doesn't correct errors.

Comment: No, all I did was indent. You are correct. This will not correct any errors. However, I often find that when seeing things indented--whether it's code or SQL--an elusive challenge often jumps out at me.